# Meteor App on Heroku Redirects to Root-url on Custom Domain

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, dns, tld

I have a Meteor app that mysteriously redirects to the registered root url, when a new custom domain with different tld is registered and tried to be accessed. This happens only with custom domains… Please note that it is the [root url](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl) that it’s redirected to, not the …herokuapp.com url…

Some other, perhaps important, detail is that this happens quite intermittently; meaning it doesn't always happen and mostly happens if the client has previously loaded the root url or another custom url pointing to the same app.

What could be the reason and how to overcome that?

I can verify that the reason was not at my DNS configuration level, nor at any Heroku configuration I have done. But perhaps I need to do further?

I do know that this has to do with different top-level domains and how servers act toward that... Some of them like .app require SSL to work and so on, and that can be weird sometimes... But some others like .com and .market also redirect to the root url when registered as custom url and tried to be loaded in the browser...

So how to overcome the issue and have the same app running in different domains without mysterious/unwanted redirects??

Answer (score 1):

The reason was indeed due to the force-ssl package from the core Meteor.

The package redirects to the [Meteor.absoluteUrl()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl) if the connection isn't registered securely (HTTPS/SSL). Therefore the problem have appeared.